# w3m: Can't load http://localhost:8080

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, debian, w3m

I get this message when i try to running jenkins (localhost:8080) on a debian server.

Do you have any idea about what's wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: The server is not up?

Answer (score 1):

see if it's actually listening on the port 8080, you can make sure using

```
netstat -nlp | grep 8080
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Armin.

I got this :

tcp6  0  0 :::8080    :::*    LISTEN     2243/java

by the way, now i can access by w3m http://localhost:8080

BUT, i got this in the bottom 

localhost contacted. Waiting for reply

(and obviously, it take so much time, without response)

Comment: I guess that your application is only listening on Ipv6, you should either disable ipv6 interface or alter your code to listen on ipv4